# Insert first item from a duplicate table into a none duplicate temp table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert first item from a duplicate table (sup_00063186105 ) into a none duplicate temp table (temp1).

Here are the table scripts

```
CREATE TABLE temp1 (
  StoreID INT,
  SaleID INT,
  ItemID INT,
  SKU VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE sup_00063186105 (
  StoreID INT,
  SaleID INT,
  ItemID INT,
  SKU VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO sup_00063186105 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
VALUES (8245, 48699, 486991001, '235060P');
INSERT INTO sup_00063186105 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
VALUES (8245, 48699, 486991002, '235060P');
INSERT INTO sup_00063186105 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
VALUES (8245, 48699, 486991002, '235060P');
INSERT INTO sup_00063186105 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
VALUES (8245, 48699, 486991002, '250780P');
INSERT INTO sup_00063186105 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
VALUES (8245, 48699, 486991002, '250781P');
```

Here is the screenshot of sup_00063186105

[image]

Here are the steps I tried

First I created temp1

```
insert into temp1(StoreID,SaleID, SKU)
select distinct StoreID,SaleID,SKU from sup_00063186105
```

[image]

Then I want to insert first matched itemID from sup_00063186105 into this temp1 table, how do I do this? I tried with merge into and update, it just does not like duplicates. I don't want to do this in PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions include using a correlated sub-query in an `UPDATE` and aggregating:

```sql
UPDATE temp1 t
SET itemid = ( SELECT MIN(itemid)
               FROM   sup_00063186105 s
               WHERE  s.storeid = t.storeid
               AND    s.saleid  = t.saleid
               AND    s.sku     = t.sku );
```

or you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp1 dst
USING (
  SELECT storeid, saleid, sku, MIN(itemid) AS itemid
  FROM   sup_00063186105
  GROUP BY storeid, saleid, sku
) src
ON (   src.storeid = dst.storeid
   AND src.saleid  = dst.saleid
   AND src.sku     = dst.sku )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET itemid = src.itemid;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pecRDr1J)

Comment: Thanks, I like your first solution, it looks concise!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution myself. Good to see if there is a better answer.

```
UPDATE temp1
SET ItemID = (
  SELECT ItemID
  FROM (
    SELECT StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreID, SaleID, SKU ORDER BY ItemID) AS rn
    FROM sup_00063186105
  ) subq
  WHERE subq.StoreID = temp1.StoreID
  AND subq.SaleID = temp1.SaleID
  AND subq.SKU = temp1.SKU
  AND rn = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative script without creating temp1

```
INSERT INTO temp1 (StoreID, SaleID, ItemID, SKU)
SELECT StoreID, SaleID, MIN(ItemID) AS ItemID, SKU
FROM sup_00063186105
GROUP BY StoreID, SaleID, SKU;
```